# Git does it again - Mixes up code and repository instead of having a nice .git folder on doing a clone and that is just half of the story

Tags: git, version-control

I wanted to be sure that after creating my 1st cut and storing my repo, I could extract it again but to a different location rather than my current working directory. So these were my steps in my workflow, which even after a whole day or more I thought I had understood, but had I?

I have this setup of git on my PC.

```
paul@homepc ~ (master)
$ git config --list
gui.recentrepo=C:/My_codebase
core.worktree=C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/SeleniumWebDriver
```

My git repo below has all the code, this is the one I am going to clone.

```
paul@homepc ~ (master)
$ ls -alrt c:/My_codebase
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ    28672 Mar 23 18:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 Internet Administ        0 Mar 24 12:30 .
drwxr-xr-x   12 Internet Administ     4096 Mar 24 21:14 .git
```

`Testproj3` is where I want to recreate my clone of `my_codebase`. See below that it is not there:

```
paul@homepc ~ (master)
$ cd C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3
sh.exe": cd: C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3: No such file or directory
```

Okay, okay, I will make it...

```
paul@homepc ~ (master)
$ cd C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode

paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ mkdir testproj3
```

Git still thinks that I already have a working tree. Fair enough. Can't I have another one? I might want 2 working tress to try out different things.

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ cd testproj3

paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3 (master)
$ git clone "c:/My_codebase/.git" .
fatal: working tree 'C:\Users\paul\JavaCode\SpringHibernateCode\SeleniumWebDriver' already exists.
```

Ok ok, maybe I have to tell git that there is another worktree area to use, so I use the explicit worktree parameter. But then even though `Testproj3` is empty, it thinks maybe because a folder exists, it has already been created.

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3 (master)
$ git --work-tree="C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3" clone "c:/My_codebase" .
fatal: working tree 'C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3' already exists.
```

So I try and help git and remove the folder and hope that this will work now:

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3 (master)
$ cd ..

paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ rm testproj3
rm: `testproj3' is a directory

paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ rmdir testproj3
```

And I think git has done what I think it should do...or has it?

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ git --work-tree="C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3" clone "c:/My_codebase/.git" 
"C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3"
Cloning into 'C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3'...
done.
Checking out files: 100% (61/61), done.
```

When I really really look carefully, I notice that git has mixed up the `.git` repo files along with my `src`, `resultOutput`, and `bin` folders, which are genuinely part of my code:

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ ls -alrt ./testproj3
total 20
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 info
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ     4096 Mar 25 00:40 hooks
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ       73 Mar 25 00:40 description
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ     4096 Mar 25 00:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 refs
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ      107 Mar 25 00:40 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ     8192 Mar 25 00:40 objects
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 logs
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ      391 Mar 25 00:40 config
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ       23 Mar 25 00:40 HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ     3439 Mar 25 00:40 .classpath
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 bin
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 .settings
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ      393 Mar 25 00:40 .project
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ        0 Mar 25 00:40 src
drwxr-xr-x   11 Internet Administ     4096 Mar 25 00:40 resultOutput
-rw-r--r--    1 Internet Administ     5976 Mar 25 00:40 index
drwxr-xr-x    1 Internet Administ     4096 Mar 25 00:40 .
```

So I am forced to clean up after git! What has happened here? Why has it not separated it's `.git` stuff out into a neat folder? Not only that, it seems to have even given the source folder `testproj3` the `hidden` attribute!

[image: explorer showing that working dir folder is marked hidden]

Are these bugs of this only in the preview version? Is it because I am using Git Bash on Windows? So it is not perfect? Surely not.

Comment: In this case, by git, I assume you're referring to yourself ? ;)

Comment: I guess this Git got to me. Even we developers are emotional animals. Actually on a professional note I think either I will have to give up the use of the command line usage namely Git Bash and use SourceTree a Gui for Git or if these basic work flows are causing so much problems who cares for all that flexibility if I have to think so much before I attempt to use this tool - maybe I should try mercurial and see if that Distributed VC gives me the same headache - I would not want such hassle in a production env - you want your tools to be explicit state the +ve - this Git is not that!!!!

Comment: @user1561783 Please do not used ALL CAPS in your questions, it makes them hard to read and it looks like you're yelling at us.

Comment: @user1561783 is there a reason that you're trying to configure the `gui.recentrepo` and `core.worktree` settings? People usually don't mess with those unless they're trying to do something unconventional with Git. ***What is the original problem that you were trying to solve?***

Comment: Just as a side note, when I personally just want to have another working copy, all I do is make another local clone, I don't have to mess around with worktree settings and stuff like that. A default clone might copy the entire repo again, depending on your platform, but if your repo isn't very big to begin with, then the extra space shouldn't be an issue. If that is an issue, I'm sure there are ways to work around that, I'll have to do some research to see what they are first though.

Comment: @user1561783 I cleaned up your question for you, it was a lot of work :P In the future, you can help us to help you by writing clear, non-emotional questions. Also, I've been using Git Bash on Windows for about 2+ years, and have never had the kind of problems that you are experiencing. None of the "preview" versions have ever given me trouble (I've used preview versions back from Git v1.7.8).

Comment: I have not made up this problem. All the info for recreating the error is there in my question. Edward has actually helped me understand this probable bug in Git where local env parameters might be getting confused with the global ones you have set up

Comment: In the spirit of [giveupandusetables](https://web.archive.org/web/20130420073730/http://giveupandusetables.com/) for CSS, I'd say "just give up and clone again".

Comment: btw Dan Dascalescu was intrigued by the link in your blog .... https://web.archive.org/web/20130420073730/http://giveupandusetables.com/ ... when it encounters the http: bit in your URL does it automatically redirect. And, coming back to your comment - are you saying even though CSS is touted as an alternative to tables - in terms of "getting it to work" tables are better - meaning you are sympathizing with the frustration of my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3 (master)
$ git clone "c:/My_codebase/.git" .
fatal: working tree 'C:\Users\paul\JavaCode\SpringHibernateCode\SeleniumWebDriver' already exists.
```

There is no way you would get that error message unless you have set the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable.  Unset that.

> WHAT HAS HAPPENED HERE ??? WHY HAS IT NOT SEPARATED IT'S .git stuff out into a neat folder

Because you specified `--work-tree` on the command line, which overrides the sanity checks that it put in place.  Don't do that.

Unset `GIT_WORK_TREE` and run `git clone <path_to_origin>` and let it create the directories itself, instead of trying to force it.  `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `--work-tree` flag are useful options when you need them, but are very much not necessary in a normal workflow.  That you're trying to use them in this very standard workflow is a red flag that something is not right.

Comment: Thanks Edward - you were right I had given Git too many options to work with - the same env var declared GLOBALLY and differently locally on my command line - there must be a bug in how it makes it choice - I would have assumed that it should read what's there on my command line - so I did the following UNSET both Git_dir and git_work_tree and followed that up with a `$ git clone "c:/My_codebase" "C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3"` and it has behaved correctly without mixing up the files in .git with what is there in my actual code

Comment: Thanks Edward - The reason why I had set a global GIT_WORK_TREE was so that I could have my repo and my working code directory separate. I did not want to overwrite my repo while I was testing my app in my code directory accidentally - which is what one could easily do. This is the first VCS where your repo could be hosted within your working directory by default and that is why I used the global env vars to separate the two out -- and all this trouble started when I then wanted a second working directory and that is how I started down the clone part which is where I hit this bug with Git

Comment: I would argue that it's not a bug, it's just doing what you told it to do, but I certainly understand your frustration.  One could argue that Git should detect that this is not the sort of configuration that you probably want, but the contrary argument is that when you *do* want this sort of setup, you should be able to get it through the environment variables and command-line options.  Git is very much of the Unix "give you enough rope to hang yourself" philosophy.

Comment: I am glad you understand this angst. And, I think this question should be rightly aired and it's reputation as a question upgraded - after all there will be others struggling with a similar issue and wondering why it does not work. I liked the Unix analogy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't clone the .git folder. You clone the folder that contains the .git folder.

```
git clone "c:/My_codebase" .
```

Finally, you really should read up on the basics of git: http://gitolite.com/gcs.html#(8)

Comment: Thanks Carl I think I tried that - so for good measure i tried it again and it did the same thing - it mixed up cloned code and the .git files all in one .... paul@homepc ~/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode (master)
$ git --work-tree="C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3" clone "c:/My_codebase" 
"C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3"
Cloning into 'C:/Users/paul/JavaCode/SpringHibernateCode/testproj3'...
done.
Checking out files: 100% (61/61), done.

Comment: get rid of the --work-tree. Do you know why are you using it? If you don't, then don't use the --work-tree option. Just plain and simple `git clone "c:/My_codebase" .`